# Customizing menus in Word (not AddIn)

Tags: c#, .net, vsto

I know how to make AddIns in Word,Excel etc. I was wondering whether I can make custom tabs in other menus of the office application

[image]

Like in left hand menu or a tab just like Add a place. Is there any way this is possible?

Answer (score 0):

The question has received a detailed answer on MSDN:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6869ee8f-3f11-4a20-aa2e-d34009a66c5c/customizing-menu-of-office-applications-not-using-addin-tab?forum=vsto

Since this site does not approve of pure linked answers I'm copying the response (my own) below.

"The menu displayed by clicking "File" is called the "Backstage". Yes, you can add a custom tab there. The Backstage is part of Ribbon XML, so you'd need to add a Ribbon XML part to your project. And if it has a Ribbon Designer you'd need to incorporate that functionality into the Ribbon XML and remove the Designeer (a VSTO project cannot have both).

You CANNOT add a custom tab as you describe in Save As.

You can find more information about working with the Backstage from these articles"

Since the hyperlinks don't paste, here's the article from which those hyperlinks were taken:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/ba8c9d0b-7312-4503-8167-f2ef86f17435/information-on-the-office-fluent-ui-ribbon-for-developers?forum=officegeneral